# Launchy: Hot keys won't work in xmonad

Tags: arch-linux, xmonad

OS:Arch Linux
Tiling manager: xmonad with unagi

I installed the package [launchy](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/launchy/) and I managed to set the hot key to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (it's the only program that uses this hotkey). However nothing, happens if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Also dmenu works without trouble. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your Xmonad configuration?

Comment: Did you start launchy?